# Not displaying the character before the .(dot) when i am using @html.label

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

When i use @html.label, not displaying the result before the .(dot) until displaying correct result as in model when i use .
in Model.Name is "Venus.Clinic-RegNo-097".

```
@Html.Label(Model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" }) 
<label class="control-label">@Model.Name</label>
```

> Output is in below picture.
>   [image]

Comment: The 1st parameter is the name of the property your binding to. Use `@Html.Label("yourPropertyName", Model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" }) `

Comment: Thanks for help me.